# Array sobrescrevendo elementos

Tags: java, arraylist

Eu fiz o método `registraReclamacao()` nessa classe e toda vez que chamo ele na main, ele sobrescreve e só armazena o último registro.

```
package testelp2;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Registro {

    ArrayList<Atributos> reclamacao = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();

    Atributos atributos = new Atributos();

    public void registraReclamacao() {
        atributos.setNumeroIdentificacao(random.nextInt(1000));
        System.out.println("Reclamação Nº " + atributos.getNumeroIdentificacao());
        System.out.println("Rua: ");
        atributos.setRua(s.next());
        System.out.println("Número da casa: ");
        atributos.setNumeroCasa(s.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Bairro: ");
        atributos.setBairro(s.next());
        System.out.println("Tamanho buraco (0 a 10): ");
        atributos.setTamanhoBuraco(s.nextInt());
        while(atributos.getTamanhoBuraco()<0 || atributos.getTamanhoBuraco()>10){
            System.out.println("Valor inválido, informe novamente: ");
            atributos.setTamanhoBuraco(s.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println("Localização buraco (Calçada ou rua): ");
        atributos.setLocalizacaoBuraco(s.next());
        while(!atributos.getLocalizacaoBuraco().equalsIgnoreCase("rua") && !atributos.getLocalizacaoBuraco().equalsIgnoreCase("calçada")){
            System.out.println("Localização inválida, informe novamente: ");
            atributos.setLocalizacaoBuraco(s.next());
        }
        Atributos atributos = new Atributos();
        reclamacao.add(atributos);
    }

    public ArrayList<Atributos> getReclamacao() {
        return reclamacao;
    }

    public void setReclamacao(ArrayList<Atributos> reclamacao) {
        this.reclamacao = reclamacao;
    }

    public void excluirReclamacao() {
        if (reclamacao.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Lista de reclamações vazia");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Reclamações disponíveis: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < reclamacao.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Nº " + atributos.getNumeroIdentificacao());
            }
            System.out.println("Número a ser excluído: ");
            int num = s.nextInt();
            while(num != atributos.getNumeroIdentificacao()) {
                System.out.println("Número inexistente, informe novamente: ");
                num = s.nextInt();
            }
            if (num == atributos.getNumeroIdentificacao()) {
                reclamacao.remove(atributos);
            }
            System.out.println("Registro excluído com sucesso");
        }
    }

    public void consultarReclamacao() {
        if (reclamacao.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Lista de reclamações vazia");
        } else {
            System.out.println(atributos.toString());
        }
    }

    public void registraConserto() {
        System.out.println("Número da reclamação: ");
        int num = s.nextInt();
        if (num != atributos.getNumeroIdentificacao()) {
            System.out.println("Reclamação Inexistente");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Valor do conserto: ");
            double valorConserto = s.nextDouble();
        String data = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        String hora = "h:mm - a";
        String data1, hora1;
        java.util.Date agora = new java.util.Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formata = new SimpleDateFormat(data);
        data1 = formata.format(agora);
        formata = new SimpleDateFormat(hora);
        hora1 = formata.format(agora);
        System.out.println("Conserto realizado no dia "+data1 +" às " + hora1 +  "");
        System.out.println("Valor: R$"+valorConserto);
        }
    }
}
```

Classe main onde chamo o método pelo switch case

```
package testelp2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Atendimento {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int opcao = 0;
        String res = null;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Registro registro = new Registro();
        do {

            System.out.println("1) Registrar reclamação");
            System.out.println("2) Excluir reclamação");
            System.out.println("3) Consultar reclamação");
            System.out.println("4) Registrar conserto");
            opcao = s.nextInt();

            switch (opcao){
            case 1:
                registro.registraReclamacao();
                break;
            case 2:
                registro.excluirReclamacao();
                break;
            case 3:
                registro.consultarReclamacao();
                break;
            case 4:
                registro.registraConserto();
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Deseja voltar ao Menu? S/N: ");
            res = s.next();
            while(!res.equalsIgnoreCase("s") && !res.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                System.out.println("Opção inválida, informe novamente: ");
                res = s.next();
            }
            if(res.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                System.out.println("A Secretaria de Obras agradece seu contato");
            }
        } while (res.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));

    }

}
```

Comment: `Random`?!?!? Não faça isto. Diga o que deseja fazer, isto está bem ruim.

Comment: Foi o professor quem pediu para atribuir um random para cada registro...

Comment: Então nem vou mexer nisso, não dá uma coisa ruim assim.

Comment: ajuda ai brother kkkkk, só com o array mesmo.

Comment: E `Random` é literalmente mais difícil que atribuir um número sequencial.

Comment: Pra que vandalizar sua pergunta?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No método `registraReclamacao` existe essa linha: `Atributos atributos = new Atributos();` Ou seja. Sempre que você passar por ele, será criado um novo objeto Atributos. Por esse motivo, só é armazenado apenas o último registro.

Eu tirei mas mesmo assim não ta salvando, só salvo o último

Comment: Você usou a área de respostas para adicionar esclarecimentos ou fazer uma pergunta. Em vez disso, é melhor incluir esse conteúdo na própria pergunta. Para fazer isso, basta clicar no link [edit], que fica logo abaixo da pergunta. Assim, o conteúdo fica todo reunido em um único lugar, e quem chegar aqui não precisa ficar procurando informações em várias respostas e comentários para entender o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Você utiliza o ultimo objeto `Atributos` criado dentro do `registraReclamacao()`:

```
Atributos atributos = new Atributos();

public void registraReclamacao() {
    atributos.setNumeroIdentificacao(...
```

E exatamente antes de adicionar à lista cria um novo:

```
...
Atributos atributos = new Atributos();
reclamacao.add(atributos);
```

Logo não vai adicionar aquele que acabou de configurar mas sim um vazio.

Aproveite e tire o `Random`, que ele não deve ser utilizado como identificador em nenhum caso pois pode-lhe gerar `ids` iguais criando um problema no sistema.

Troque por:

```
//Atributos atributos = new Atributos(); // não precisa desta linha aqui

//aqui guarda o numero da reclamação para não ter que fazer random que não lhe garante 
//que o numero da reclamação é único
int numReclamacao = 1; 

public void registraReclamacao() {
    Atributos atributos = new Atributos(); //quando vai registar cria um novo
    atributos.setNumeroIdentificacao(numReclamacao++); //aqui usa o numero da reclamacao

    System.out.println("Reclamação Nº " + atributos.getNumeroIdentificacao());

    ... //resto tudo igual

    //Atributos atributos = new Atributos(); //este também já não é preciso
    reclamacao.add(atributos);
}
```

Tem muitos outros erros/falhas de lógica no código, mas era preciso extender me demasiado para os abranger todos.

Answer (score 0):

No método: `registraReclamacao`existe essa linha:

```
Atributos atributos = new Atributos();
```

Ou seja. Sempre que você passar por ele, será criado um novo objeto Atributos. Por esse motivo, só é armazenado apenas o último registro.

Comment: Eu tirei, mas mesmo assim só salva o último...

Comment: Tirou e colocou no escopo global?